# How to create referencing variables?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making an app for practice. This app shares with a simple model through AppDelegate. To manipulate the model, I got an NSDictionary object from the model and allocate it to a viewController property. but It seems too verbose.

```
// viewController.h
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *bookDetail;
@property (nonatomic, strong) bookModel *modelBook;

// viewController.m
- (void)setLabel {
        self.label_name.text = self.bookDetail[@"name"];
        self.label_author.text = self.bookDetail[@"author"];
    }
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    id appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    self.modelBook = [appDelegate modelBook];
    self.bookDetail = self.modelBook.bookList[self.modelBook.selectedId];

    [self setLabel];

    self.editMod = NO;
}
- (IBAction)editSave:(id)sender {
    if (self.editMod == NO) {

        ....

        [self.nameField setText:self.bookDetail[@"name"]];
        [self.authorField setText:self.bookDetail[@"author"]];

        ....

    } else {
        self.bookDetail = [@{@"name"     : self.nameField.text,
                             @"author"   : self.authorField.text} mutableCopy];
        [self setLabel];

        ....

    }
}
@end
```

`*bookDetail` work like a copy of  `self.modelBook.bookList[self.modelBook.selectedId]` not a reference. Using `self.modelBook.bookList[self.modelBook.selectedId]` works well, but I don't want to. How Can I simplify this code?

Comment: create the shared instance of bookModel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `*bookDetail` work like a copy of  `self.modelBook.bookList[self.modelBook.selectedId]` not a reference. Using `self.modelBook.bookList[self.modelBook.selectedId]` works well, but I don't want to.

Your question is not clear to me so this might be wrong, but hopefully it helps.

`bookDetail` is not a "copy" in the usual sense, rather it is a reference to the same dictionary that `self.modelBook.bookList[self.modelBook.selectedId]` references at the time the assignment to `bookDetail` *is made*.

Given that you say that using the latter "works well" is sounds as though `self.modelBook.selectedId` is changing and you expected `bookDetail` to automatically track that change and now refer to a different dictionary. That is not how assignment works.

> How Can I simplify this code?

You could add a property to your `modelBook` class[1], say `currentBook`, which returns back `bookList[selectedID]` so each time it is called you get the current book. In your code above you then use `self.modelBook.currentBook` instead of `self.bookDetail` and can remove the property `bookDetail` as unused (and incorrect).

HTH

---

[1] Note: this should be called `ModelBook` to follow naming conventions. Have you noticed the syntax coloring is incorrect? That is because you haven't followed the convention.

Comment: Thank you very much. For me, the allocation concept of obj-c is very difficult ;)

Answer (score 1):

**Create the shared instance of BookModel then you can access it anywhere:**

Write this in bookModel:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
    static bookModel *sharedInstance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedInstance = [[bookModel alloc] init];
        // Do any other initialisation stuff here
    });
    return sharedInstance;
}
```

> Then you can access this like bookModel.sharedInstance.bookList